# PLSQL Code coverage Pragma coverage not working

Tags: sql, unit-testing, plsql, code-coverage

I am using the DBMS_PLSQL_CODE_COVERAGE package to get PL/SQL code coverage in the Oracle database.

I have a function called Foo. I want to skip one if block from coverage. I have used pragma coverage syntax as followed. But Still it's not get ignored from the coverage.

```
FUNCTION Foo (
   val_ IN NUMBER ) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
   IF (val_ > 100) THEN
      PRAGMA COVERAGE ('NOT_FEASIBLE');
      RETURN -1;
   ELSIF (val_ < 0) THEN
      RETURN -1;
   ELSE
      RETURN 1;
   END IF;
END Foo;
```

This is the output from the coverage.
[image: PLSQL Coverage information]

This is the query that I am using to get coverage information.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(ccb.col, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ccb.col) AS col,
       LISTAGG(ccb.covered, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ccb.col) AS covered,
       s.line,
       LISTAGG(ccb.not_feasible, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ccb.col) AS not_feasible,
       s.text
FROM   user_source s
       JOIN dbmspcc_units ccu ON s.name = ccu.name AND s.type = ccu.type
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbmspcc_blocks ccb ON ccu.run_id = ccb.run_id AND ccu.object_id = ccb.object_id AND s.line = ccb.line
WHERE  s.name = 'NEW_UTILITY_TST'
AND    s.type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
AND    ccu.run_id = 147
GROUP BY s.line, s.text
ORDER BY 3;
```

What is I am doing wrong here, not to get ignored the IF block from coverage?

Answer (score 0):

The **PRAGMA COVERAGE ("NOT_FEASIBLE")** does not mark the block as "Covered". Instead it places that code path into the **NOT_FEASIBLE** category (BTW, with coverage of zero).

You can [display the NOT_FEASIBLE count in you report as shown here:](https://rogertroller.com/2017/03/20/oracle-12-2-coverage-pragma-and-dbms_plsql_code_coverage/)

Comment: That is what I have exactly mentioned. Even Pragma has added the NOT_FEASIBLE column as 0. It should be 1. Isn't it?